# Why are the Psalms numbered this way in some Catholic Bibles?

Tags: psalms, catholic-bible

I am looking at a Catholic Bible and I see the following:

- PSALM 1
  [...]
- PSALM 9-10
  [...]
- PSALM 51 V50 *Miserere*
- PSLAM 52 V 51
  [...]
- PSALM 150

*Please see image below.*

What accounts for this numbering?

It is not a straight 1 thru 150 numbering. For example there is Psalm 9-10 and Psalm 51 has V50 alongside it.

I am looking for a Catholic explanation sought but I assume a Bible scholar ought to be able to explain it.

---

Image produced from *The Jerusalem Bible Popular Edition.*

[image: The Psalms]

Comment: Do you mean, why are the psalms in the order they're in?

Comment: Exactly which 'catholic bible' do you mean? Photos might help, because I have no idea what the psalm 51 thing means.

Comment: @curiousdannii See below. A user did not have the same difficulty as you did and they are on the right track. I would respond if you commented and they were say 3/4 VTC.

Comment: @curiousdannii meaning there was say one comment that had a few votes to it + there were a few VTC. That would be a criteria i will use going forward. I may review it if it does not work.

Comment: I would agree that this question would be better with more information, such as a photo.  I had no idea what you were talking about either, but the answer below cleared up the doubt.

Comment: @curiousdannii You are welcome! Sorry they are a bit unclear. I am sorry for what DavidStratton termed *our butting heads*. I hope we can move forward for the good of the site. PS Sometimes in hindsight it turns out better as this question has and the other re: *marital ...*. You work hard. PPS My participation over next several days to a week will be sporadic.

Comment: An even better picture. So much clearer! 'Miserere' looks like a name that's been given to Ps 51.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a difference in numbering between the Hebrew (Masoretic) text and the Greek and Latin (Septuagint and Vulgate). Psalms 9 and 10 in the Hebrew get combined into one as do Ps 114 & 115. Psalms 116 and 147 both get split in two.

Most Protestant Bibles follow the Hebrew numbering while most Catholic and Orthodox ones follow the Greek.

I suspect the reason for the difference is that the numbers were added to the Hebrew and Greek manuscripts at a later date and there were different opinions as to where one finished and the next began.

---

- Cf. [Septuagint (LXX) numbering of the Psalms | The Orthodox Church in America](http://oca.org/liturgics/outlines/septuagint-numbering-psalms).
- Cf. [Note on the different numbering of the 150 Psalms | psalmen.wursten.be](http://psalmen.wursten.be/psalms_numbering.htm).

Comment: This is good, but it would be better if you could add references to support it.

Comment: What about Ps 51 and 52?

Comment: My main source was my memory backed up by Wikipedia. http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psalms#Numbering

Comment: @curiousdannii - I don't think there is anything special about Ps 51&52 - just that the numbers are out of sync because of the difference with 9&10.